# Should a scheduled action execute with criteria DateTime in the past greater than NOW()+2

Tags: process-builder, scheduled-action

If a decision criteria has a rule like this:

```
[CustomObject__c].Send_DateTime__c >= NOW()+2
```

And the value of `Send_DateTime__c` is `Nov 9th` (i.e. a value which makes the Immediate action execute)

And the first scheduled action is set to execute at:

```
0 Hours After Send_DateTime__c
```

Will any of the subsequent scheduled actions execute?

Because surely the above rule will no longer be true, and therefore the scheduled action will be removed from the queue?

Therefore, won't all the scheduled actions not run:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experiments, it appears that Process Builder only checks the criteria during a create/edit, but not before executing actions. In other words, if the last edit was successful in placing or keeping the action in the queue, it will execute, even if the criteria would no longer be met.

Basically, the exact opposite of your assumption that the actions would be removed. As an exception to *that* behavior, obviously, is if you set a field update that modifies the record, then it will be removed from the queue, but not before doing all of the scheduled actions that were active at the moment the Flow Wait resumed.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, but doesn't that mean the documentation wrong/misleading? `For processes that start when a record is created or edited, scheduled actions remain in the queue only as long as the criteria for those actions are still valid. If a record no longer matches the criteria, Salesforce removes the scheduled actions for the record from the queue.` taken from [How Does Salesforce Process Scheduled Actions?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled_processing.htm&type=5)

Comment: @Robs the docs are correct on behavior in situations not involving current-time based formulass and cross-object references. Once you throw those in to the mix, things start behaving badly. I feel like it's probably a bug, and either way, it's an edge case. Either the docs are omitting this important detail, or there's an implementation bug. I wouldn't know which without submitting a case.